# A java web application with struts2:Success.But

Tags: java, jar, struts2

i have done self study on learning struts 2. i have used one code available in internet.It is working fine after i got lot of struggle on selecting only the jar files versions that suggested by the author.

i am not having any knowledge on web programming.why different versions of the jar files are not supported.How to resolve this issue for future learning.

the example is taken from http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-27

i have done some study on maven.will it resolve the issues.(i guess it is)

i have seen xwork jar file in the given tutorial.But in the latest versions of the struts 2 this jar file has been changed to xwork-core.

i have done execution with the following replacement.
1)xwork-2.0.6.jar (or) xwork-core2.3.1.1.jar
2)freemarker-2.3.18
3)ognl-3.0.3.jar
4)struts2-core-2.3.18
5)commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

i got errors with the two cases.

the error is

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/opensymphony/xwork2/util/logging/Logger;

IS THERE ANY IN DEPTH REASON FOR THIS>

Thank you all..

Comment: better download sample application from official S2 website to see what required jars you need to have if you are not familiar with Maven and wants things quickely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot randomly upgrade single jar files without upgrading their dependencies: upgrade *all* the jars.

To solve this problem in the future, (a) look at the jars shipped in the distro, (b) use Maven or similar and stop doing dependency management by hand--it's not worth it, and it's difficult.

Comment: In the latest version the xwork is replaced with xwork-core and i used all the latest versions of the jar files.there itself i got the error.

Comment: @PratapMurukutla Then update your question; it only says you updated struts-core. We can't see what you're deploying--without a list of jars, we'd just be guessing.

Comment: @PratapMurukutla You're missing a few jars if those are the only ones you're deploying--look at the "blank" sample app for the minimum jars necessary to run. Once you get a simple app running, I'd strongly recommend using automated dependency management--for simple usecases, Maven is quite easy to use.